# Where can we find the description of how Maharaja Parikshith (as a baby) was saved by Sri Krishna?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavata-purana

I am looking for references on the story of Sri Krishna saving Parikshith. Specifically looking for references to section where Sri Krishna is said to have touched the charred body of the baby, vowing to his brahmacharya and truthfullness.

Comment: Related. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7047/upapandavas-why-were-they-killed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The details is mentioned in many chapter of Mahabharata and Bhagavata Purana but as you are "specifically looking for references to section where Sri Krishna is said to have touched the charred body of the baby, vowing to his brahmacharya and truthfullness", I think you are looking for passage from [Mahabharata: Aswamedha Parva: Anugita Parva: Section LXIX](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14069.htm):

> That foremost of beings, hearing those heart-rending lamentations of hers, touched water and withdrew the (force of the) Brahma-weapon.[1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14070.htm#fn_184) That hero of unfading glory, belonging to the race of the Dasarhas, promised to give the child his life. Then he of pure soul, said these words in the hearing of the whole universe,--'O Uttara, I never utter an untruth. My words will prove true. I shall revive this child in the presence of all creatures. Never before have I uttered an untruth even in jest. Never have I turned back from battle. (By the merit of those acts) let this child revive! As righteousness is dear to me, as Brahmanas are specially dear to me, (by the merit of that disposition of mine) let Abhimanyu's son, who is born dead, revive! Never hath a misunderstanding arisen between me and my friend Vijaya. Let this dead child revive by that truth! As truth and righteousness are always established in me, let this dead child of Abhimanyu revive (by the merit of these)! As Kansa and Kesi have been righteously slain by me, let this child revive today by that truth!' After these words were uttered by Vasudeva, that child, O foremost one of Bharata's race, became animate and began gradually to move, O monarch.'

Comment: This is an excellent reference. In addition to the truthfullness, the narration I have heard also mentions about Sri Krishna vowing to his celibacy being true as well. Is that part of the sanskrit text that might have been changed when being translated?

Comment: @Ambi Few article like [this](https://www.poornsamarpan.in/article/2015/12/16/lord-krishna-restores-life-dead-newborn-child-and-name-him-parikshit) say "If I follow truth, Dharma and Brahmacharya always, this child will be alive".but I checked Sanskrit-Hindi version of Mahabharata from Gitapress and couldn't find the word Brahmacharya or celibacy.. as mentioned [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23977/12304) celibacy seems to be hidden quality of Dharma (righteousness) so may be indirectly Krishna said so or some other version of Mahabharata might contain the specific word celibacy

Answer (score 6):

You can find the story in Skanda 1 chapter 8 in the Bhagavata purana

https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/8

However this is not in great detail, Mahabharata may have description in greater detail.